# How to make new stacklayout push all current contents down in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a custom message alert which is a stacklayout that pops up:

```
var msgAlert = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                StyleClass = new List<string> { "Message" },
                Padding = 10,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
```

On some pages it pushes the contents down and pops up on the top, but for some pages it just sits on top of the page covering the top, and I'm not sure how to make it so that it pushes the contents down for every page.

Are there any properties I can give it to make it push all contents down no matter what?

Thanks

edit:
One the page where it doesn't work, it is part of a tabbed page, being called from the tabbedpage parent in another xaml file:

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <pages:Doesn'tPushPage
      Title="{x:Static Doesn'tPushPage}"
      x:Name="Doesn'tPushPage">
    </pages:Doesn'tPushPage>
```

This is the parent calling the child, where the child is the problem xaml page

Comment: how are you displaying the alert?  What is different between the pages where it works and the ones where it doesn't?

Comment: @Jason Weird thing is there's no difference I can point out in the pages where it works and it doesn't work, the xaml pages are basically identical, maybe some differences in the pagemodels but nothing I can single out. The one difference is that one page is part of a TabbedPage, I'll post the code and pic in an edit.

edit: Got a word wrong

Comment: @Jason Other than that there's no difference, the tabbedpage child xaml page is the exact same as the other pages that work, it's just located in the tabbedpage which I wouldn't think makes a difference but

Comment: Can you please show us the code where you pop up the alert?

Comment: It's not that special, just `public async Task ToggleStyleCheck()
        {
            if (style == true)
            {
                NotificationMessage = Resources.styleTrue;
            }
            else (style == false)
            {
                NotificationMessage = Resources.styleFalse;
            }
        }` in the page models, the functions are the same @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: Can you give me a Minimal, Reproducible Example? I need to see the NotificationMessaging code you use in the contentPage.